# Python function called with all args given as a string

Tags: python, string, matlab, parsing, arguments

I'm building a remote API for a Python module I've written. The code will take raw strings retrieved from Matlab via UDP, parse it, and make calls to the API via these strings. In effect, I want to interface with my API on the Matlab side with Python syntax.

Say I have a function:

```
 commands = {'foo':foo}
 def foo(arg1=default, arg2=default):
     ...
     return bar
```

In Matlab, I send this over UDP:

```
'foo(arg1='in1', arg2='in2')'
```

On the Python server side, I have a dictionary with function names as keys, the corresponding functions themselves as values. I'm able to call simple functions w/ no arguments, or simple args, but on more complicated stuff I can't get this to work.

So, I have the function, I have the args as a string, **how can I pass the args to the function as this string in the most direct way possible?**

I.e.

```
command = commands['foo']
command(argString)
```

If at all possible, I'd like to avoid using kwargs. I have studied the similar questions, but haven't found anything that works yet.

**Edit**
Here is some more concrete code; server is already running, UDP packet gets dealt with in an 'interrupt' where determine_command gets called.

The matlab packet being sent is:

```
cmd = ['get_surrounding_elevation(mode=''coords'',window=3,' ...
'coordinates=Coordinate(36.974117, -122.030796))'];
```

The Python end:

```
def func_explode(self, s):
    pattern = r'(\w[\w\d_]*)\((.*)\)$'
    match = re.match(pattern, s)
    if match:
        return list(match.groups())
    else:
        return []

def determine_command(self, command):
    """
    Parse raw input and execute specified function with args
    :param command: The raw command retrieved from UDP
    :return: the command that was executed
    """

    funcArray = self.func_explode(command)
    cmd = self.commands[funcArray[0]]
    args = funcArray[1]

    print cmd(mode='coords', window=3, coordinates=Coordinate(36.974117, -122.030796)) #this works
    try:
        cmd(eval(args))  #this, and other permutations of, doesn't work
        print cmd
    except:
        print "Command Not Found"

    return cmd
```

Comment: Can you give a simple reproducible example of what argString looks like and what `commands` looks like?

Comment: And also how the argString is created.

Comment: It seems pretty clunky to make API calls by sending a string of python code. Why not send some more structured data, like some JSON describing the function to be called and its arguments?

Comment: "I'd like to avoid using kwargs." Why?

Comment: I'm adding an example now - see the edits. @jme: agreed, clunky, but more natural. Maybe I'll make the switch; however, still doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @msw: would involve rewriting a good chunk of code, also, I'm still going to want to make API calls in straight python. If you can make a good case for it, perhaps, but right now I just need to get a darn arg string into a function!

Comment: A good case for it might be that you are failing at doing it your way and appear not to be able to articulate what "your way" is. That's good indication that you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: I have a function, and I have arguments to that function as a string, need to put the two together and I'm done. No need for the attitude.

Comment: 1) Actually, I'd argue that JSON is more natural, and it's how this sort of thing is often done. 2) It's unclear *why* you'd have to re-write a bunch of code if you used **kwargs. What code? Otherwise, you could just `eval` the string of arguments into a dictionary and splat that into your command. 3) Or you could just go ahead and `eval` the whole string, command included, with the usual disclaimer about this being unsafe for unfiltered input, and generally a poor way of going about things.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def foo(*args):
    for a in args:
         print a

#main for test
# call as foo (a1, a2) etc

foo(1, 2, 3)
foo("abc", 1)
```

Output:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> abc
>
> 1